# Whenever I try to initialize schema in next.js it shows error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-dev-server, yup

Whenever I try to initialize yup schema in next.js its shows the following error.

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
const experienceSchema = Yup.object.shape({
  experience: Yup.string().required(),
})
```

The error I'm getting

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

This is similar to every page wherever I try to import yup. I tried with different versions also but still, the error persists.

Yup Version : 0.32.10

Next Version : 12.0.8

Answer (score 1):

`yup.object().shape` vs `yup.object.shape` is the issue. I made a stackblitz that shows all and your code working, it simply consoles out value

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-7etrjq?file=pages%2Findex.js

Answer (score 0):

Brackets missing in the object.
I got the error.
It should be this.

```
const experienceSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  experience: Yup.string().required(),
})
```

instead of this

```
const experienceSchema = Yup.object.shape({
  experience: Yup.string().required(),
})
```